# Google app engine data query returns 0 results

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I'm attempting login using google app engine with objectify but since the Google User object doesn't have enough information I created a local Entity that looks like so :

```
@Cache
@Entity
public abstract class UserData extends RoleUser implements UserDetails {

    protected String firstName;
    protected String middleName;
    protected String lastName;


    protected boolean enabled;
    protected String phoneNumber;

    @Index
    protected String email;

    @Index
    protected String userName;
```

and I have a subclass for a GoogleUser like so :

```
@Subclass
public class GoogleUser extends UserData {

    private String googleUserId;
    private String authDomain;
```

Finally the query that I run to see if my custom entity was created for a specific email is like so :

```
public boolean isNewUser(String email){
    int count = ofy().load().type(GoogleUser.class).filter("userName =", email).count();
    logger.debug("Total accounts for email: |" + email + "| \t Count: " + count);
    return count == 0;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the query returns 0 results even though I see the entity when I look at datastore through admin on my local appengine server. I'm at the end of my rope here so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you ruled out [eventual consistency](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/#h.tf76fya5nqk8)?

Comment: @tx802 Yes I don't think it's a replication problem since I've restarted the server and I see that the field is indexed in admin. I assume that once it shows up in admin that it is ready for querying but I could be wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`objectify` does not index subclasses by default. You have to explicitly enable this for each subclass, like so:

```
@Subclass(index=true)
public class GoogleUser extends UserData {

    private String googleUserId;
    private String authDomain;
```

Note that if you have changed the polymorphic hierarchy of your class you will need to re-save your entity for indexing to work.

Little tip: Having no operator in the filter means ==
Your query can be written like this

```
int count = ofy().load().type(GoogleUser.class).filter("userName", email).list();
```

Comment: I could kiss you right now. Ugh. I even tried creating a manual index for each. I just dropped all my entities and retried it, works perfectly. Thank you so very much, and thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if

```
.filter("userName =", email)
```

should have been

```
.filter("email =", email)
```

Comment: I've tried both actually, for Google accounts the userName is the email, and I've filled both fields with the email.


 2016-07-31 15:56:39 DEBUG UserDao:54 - Total accounts for email: |test@example.com|   Count: 0